# Is Ubuntu the operating system or is Linux considered the operating system?

Tags: kernel

I realize Ubuntu is built atop Linux source, including the GUI perspective using X, etc.

It is a lightly abstracted deviation of a standard Linux protocol GUI-based OS in that it doesn't natively differ from desktop Linux, such as how Android does without native X support implemented.

However, when referring to a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, should one refer to Ubuntu, the kernel software part and the originating source, or should one refer to Ubuntu, the software on top of Linux?

Because it is all confusing saying I have "Linux on my desktop" and "I have Ubuntu on my desktop", which can be essentially the same thing when you really consider it and break away the middleware.

Answer (score 4):

The resolution required really depends who you're talking to. Let's do a car analogy!

- You might tell a stranger you drive "a car".
- You tell somebody you're meeting later you'll be in a "Red Ford Pickup" so they can recognise you in it.
- When you call your mechanic, you explain it's a classic 1969 Ford F250 Pickup 360 V8 and you need a new exhaust for it.

You don't need to be atomically accurate all the time. If you run around telling everybody everything in the maximum detail, you'll just end up looking a bit like a weirdo-super-geek. The same applies to Linux advocacy. If you insist on telling everybody you meet you're running Ubuntu GNU/Linux with amd64 architecture, people are going to wonder *why* you're doing it.

But technically speaking, the GNU tools with Linux is its kernel together make up an operating system. Ubuntu as the distribution makes that all work and layers on useful tools like display servers, window managers and the applications.

But if you're just bragging about what you're running, Linux or Ubuntu will do. People will get the gist.

Answer (score 3):

You are more or less saying the same controversy as "Linux" and "GNU/Linux", but instead of "GNU/Linux" you are talking about "Ubuntu":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_naming_controversy

> GNU/Linux is a term promoted by the Free Software Foundation (FSF),
>   its founder Richard Stallman, and its supporters, for operating
>   systems that include GNU software and the Linux kernel. The FSF argues
>   for the term GNU/Linux because GNU was a longstanding project to
>   develop a free operating system, of which they say the kernel was the
>   last missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a collection of software, configurations and practices called a Distribution.

Linux is the Kernel on top of which everything else runs and is the Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that there's some variety of opinion on this question. Personally, I tend to think of the "operating system" as the overall last-mile product that I install on my computer, which *uses* particular packages like GNU libc and the Linux kernel to satisfy specific functional requirements.

Consider a thought experiment: If Ubuntu 14.04 included an automated, behind the scenes transition to a Hurd or Mach microkernel instead of Linux as soon as you upgraded to it, with all the other apps and libraries remaining the same (please ignore for the moment how problematic and unlikely this would be), would you consider your system to have changed "operating systems" in that process? I would say no, I ran "Ubuntu" before and after, and Ubuntu swapped out one of the pieces that it uses. The other components and the method for pulling them all together remained the same.